# TypeError: must be real number, not list; while trying to define an array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to define an array but trying to execute the code I got the following error message:

```
 Matrix=arr.array('d',[[0 for x in range(i)] for x in range(i)])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

I expected the 2d-Array to be defined and go on to the part of filling in the array, since I need a variable array that is filled in differently. I posted the code snippet in question with the error message as it is included in the error message.